# After how many hours water drunk is expelled from the body?

Tags: human-physiology

If one drinks a liter of water at 7 am when (in what span) will that water be eliminated through uresis?

Is that process influenced by any factors such as empty stomach, sleep or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time from drinking to urination depends mainly on your hydration status and the presence of food in the stomach.

Scenario: You have drunk enough fluid in the previous days, so you are normally hydrated. In the morning, you get up from the bed, urinate, drink 1 liter of water in 5 minutes and eat nothing.

Some water can come through the stomach and can be absorbed in the small intestine in about 5 minutes; the entire liter may need more than 2 hours ([sweatscience.com](https://sweatscience.com/how-quickly-is-water-absorbed-after-you-drink-it/)).

When some water is absorbed into the blood it can immediately trigger diuresis - the excretion of the urine through the kidneys into the bladder. It may take about 3 hours for the entire amount of water drunk to be excreted. So, the approximate time span (from start to end of water excretion) could be 5 - 180 minutes. But not likely the entire liter of water will be excreted, because, in the morning, you are in a slightly negative water balance, so some water will stay in your body.

If you are dehydrated before starting drinking, much less urine will be excreted in the first few hours.

If you drink after eating, the food in the stomach can delay water absorption and excretion by more than an hour. This also happens when you drink nutritional fluids, such as milk or juice.

This is from my experience and understanding basic physiology. I'll try to find some references.

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive reply, I regret I cannot upvote your or any answer, but I'm sure others will see to it.Can you clarify one thing for me, since what you say clashes with my experience: waking up at about 7:30 am I drink in the excess of half a liter water and at breakfast I have some 30 cl of milk, then at dinner at supper little more water, yet 80% of diuresis takes place during the night between 10 p.m and 7:30 am. I thought it took at least 15 hours to excrete all the water !!

Comment: If I take literally what you said about 80% diuresis happening at night, does this mean you urinate 4 times at night and once during a day? The most common reason for frequent urinating at night in healthy people is drinking in the evening. Another reason is that when you lie down, some fluid shifts from your legs toward the heart and the heart detects this as an increase of blood volume, which triggers diuresis. Also, diuresis does not occur only due to drinking but because the kidneys constantly remove waste from your blood in the form of urine.

Answer (score 0):

It is a hypothetical question which is not a true scenario I would try to explain the process of water absorption and excetrtion.

when a person consumes water it is absorbed into blood stream (liquid as well as in the form of water in food consumed). The amount of water absorbed in the stomach and how quickly water is absorbed depends, in part, on how much has been eaten. If someone is drinking water on an empty stomach, they are more likely to experience a faster rate of water absorption – as quick as 5 minutes after taking a drink. Whereas, if a person has eaten a lot of food before they drink water, the speed of absorption will slow down accordingly and absorption could take up to a few hours.

Approximately only 20% directly makes to the bladder remaining water would be utilized for performing vital function of the body.

Once the human body uses up all the water it needs to function efficiently, it begins the process of removing excess water.The water is not only excreted solely through uresis (urine is only 95% water), the other routes for water excretion is sweat, fecal route and saliva.Small droplets of water also exit the body via the breath.

As water is not excreted thought sole route is not possible to calculate the exact time taken for removal from the body.